# How can I make a django form field value not refresh if the field is not validated and user hits submit

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, jinja2

I have created an HTMl register form template, and designed it such that if there is any validation error, it outputs the error and that works fine. [Register form showing "passwords do not match" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbGt2.png) The problem I'm having is the whole form fields clear once I hit submit and the errors show up, this was if a user has a "passwords do not match error" he'd have to input all his details from scratch. I want the user to input only the fields that has errors.

> The register HTML form

```
<form method="POST" class="requires-validation" novalidate>
                          {% csrf_token %}
                      
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Firstname" required>
                            {% if form.first_name.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.first_name.errors %}
                            <span style="color:#DC3545;">
                              {{error}}
                            </span>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                         </div>

                         <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Lastname" required>
                            {% if form.last_name.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.last_name.errors %}
                            <span style="color:#DC3545;">
                              {{error}}
                            </span>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                         </div>

                         <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required>
                            {% if form.email.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                            <span style="color:#DC3545;">
                              {{error}}
                            </span>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                         </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                         <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                         {% if form.password1.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.password1.errors %}
                            <span style="color:#DC3545;">
                              {{error}}
                            </span>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm your password" required>
                            {% if form.password2.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.password2.errors %}
                            <span style="color:#DC3545;">
                              Passwords do not match, confirm and try again
                            </span>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                      </div>

                        <div class="form-button mt-3">
                          <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <span>Already have an account?<a href=""> Sign in</a></span>
                    </form>
```

> The views.py for register form

```
def register_view(request):
form = CustomUserCreationForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, f'{user.first_name}, your account has been created succesfully')
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        messages.error(request, form.errors)
return render(request, 'base/register.html', {'form' : form })
```

> The Register form model

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import UserModel
from django import forms

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Firstname'})
    )

    last_name = forms.CharField(
    label='',
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Lastname'})
    )

    email = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'})
    )

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Password'})
    )

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Password again'})
    )

        
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('email','first_name','last_name')
```

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('email','first_name','last_name')
```

Comment: You've rendered the form fields manually: `<input ...>` and haven't handled specifying the initial values either of course all the fields will get cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue, the problem is that I was rendering the form fields with <Input....> tag instead of rendering them using the Jinja tags i.e {{form.field}}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### ==== models.py ====

```
class EmployeeModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

### ==== forms.py ====

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeModel
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {

            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Employee Name'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Employee E-Mail'}),
        }
```

### ==== views.py ====

```
def EmployeeView(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      print("======= form is validated ============")
      form.save()
      messages.info(request,'Employee Added')
      return redirect("/")
    else:
      print("======= form is not validated ============")
      context= {'form':form}
      return render(request,'index.html',context)
  else:
    form = EmployeeForm()
  context= {'form':form}
  return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

### ==== html code =====

```
{% block body %}
     <div>
          {% if messages %}
          {% for msg in messages %}
               {{msg}}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
     </div> 
     <br>

     <form action="" method="POST" novalidate >
          {% csrf_token %}
          
          <p>{{form.name.label}}:{{form.name}} {{form.name.errors|striptags}} </p>
          <p>{{form.email.label}}:{{form.email}} {{form.email.errors|striptags}} </p>
               
          <p><button type="submit">Add</button></p>
          
     </form>

     

{% endblock body %}
```

### ===== output ========

[image]